# How to make a sliding dashboard similar to medium.com?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, sliding, flyout

I would like to know how to make a sliding panel on the left of the screen. The catch is that it shouldn't slide **over** the page content, but rather **pushing** the content to the right (eventually hiding a portion of the content).

a great example: the [medium.com](http://medium.com) sliding dashboard (when you click on the logo)

Bonus: I imagine you could do this either in javascript or purely is CSS, which would be better in a Ruby on Rails app?

Comment: Study their source code

Comment: I did stare at it for a bit, but I'm just a beginner in web dev, so I couldn't make sense out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this tutorial http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/13/multi-level-push-menu/.

Demo of tutorial here : http://tympanus.net/Development/MultiLevelPushMenu/